# Get the value of text box using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have the following script  :

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#edit').click(function (){
            //get
            employee_id = $('#employee_id').val();
            alert(employee_id);
            html='';

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>administrator/admin/get_employee_details/"+employee_id,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $( '#fname' ).val(response[0].f_name);
                    alert(response[0].amount);
                    $( '#sname' ).val(response[0].l_name);
                    $( '#lname' ).val(response[0].other_name);
                    $( '#expiry_date' ).val(response[0].id_no);
                    $( '#quantity_available').val(response[0].dob)
                    $( '#gender' ).val(response[0].gender);
                    $( '#maritalstatus').val(response[0].marital_status)
                    $( '#sex' ).val(response[0].gender);
                },
                error: function(data){
                }
            })
        });

    });

</script>
```

The script is supposed pick the employee_id value from the table below :

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($employee_details as $employee ):?>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td><?php echo $employee['employee_name'];?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $employee['id_no'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee['dob'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee['gender'];?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $employee['marital_status'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee['phone_no'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee['email'];?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $employee['date_added'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee['residence'];?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $employee['next_of_kin_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee['next_of_kin_relation'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee['next_of_kin_phone_no'];?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $employee['is_active'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee['department_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee['employee_class'];?></td>
            <td><a class="edit" href="#edit_details" id="edit">Edit </a></td>
            <td> <a class="delete" href="#delete_details" id="delete"  > Delete Employee</a></td>
            <input type="text" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" value="<?php echo $employee['employee_id'];?>"/>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
```

which is a hidden text field (employee_id) in the table when I click the Edit button. But when I click the link , I get an empty result with no employee_id yet I can see the employee id in the text box. How can I get the employee id from the text box for each specific row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id of an element must unique, so inside the loop use class instead of id, also move the employee_id field to a `td` element

```
<td> 
    <a class="edit" href="#edit_details">Edit </a>
</td>
<td> 
    <a class="delete" href="#delete_details" > Delete Employee</a>
    <input type="text" name="employee_id" value="<?php echo $employee['employee_id'];?>" />
</td>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('.edit').click(function () {


        //get
        var employee_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="employee_id"]').val();
        alert(employee_id);
        html = '';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>administrator/admin/get_employee_details/" + employee_id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#fname').val(response[0].f_name);
                alert(response[0].amount);
                $('#sname').val(response[0].l_name);
                $('#lname').val(response[0].other_name);
                $('#expiry_date').val(response[0].id_no);
                $('#quantity_available').val(response[0].dob)
                $('#gender').val(response[0].gender);
                $('#maritalstatus').val(response[0].marital_status)
                $('#sex').val(response[0].gender);

            },
            error: function (data) {

            }
        })

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute must be unique in your web page. You can't have 2 elements with the same `id`.

So for your links and your inputs, you must generate a different id for each row. For example you can try `id="employee_id-<?php echo $employee['employee_id'];?>"`.
But you can keep the same classes for each link and input, and use it in your javascript script code.

Then you must change your code :

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    var employee_id = this.closest('tr').find('.employee_id').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use class attribute instead of id because id cant be repeated.

<input type="text" name="employee_id" class="employee_id" value="<?php echo $employee['employee_id'];?>"/>


$('.edit').click(function() {
    var id = this.closest('tr').find('input.employee_id').val();
});
```

In Id you will be able to get employee id